# How can i display data with multi markers, multi colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a newbie in matplotlib and today i want to ask for my current problem.
Please see my code:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
colors = [0,1,1,0,1,4,1,3,2,4]
sizes = [500,500,300,300,300,500,500,300,300,300]
map1 = plt.cm.get_cmap("jet", 5)
plt.scatter(x[0:3], y[0:3], c=colors[0:3] ,s=sizes[0:3],marker="*",cmap=map1)
plt.scatter(x[3:6], y[3:6], c=colors[3:6] ,s=sizes[3:6],marker="<",cmap=map1)
plt.scatter(x[6:10], y[6:10], c=colors[6:10], s=sizes[6:10],marker="D",cmap=map1)
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(5))
plt.clim(-0.5, 4.5)
plt.show()
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpig3.png)

The problem is that i can not get the result with multiple of markers and multiple of colors. As you can see, i have a test dataset with 10 items, and i want to show 1st -> 3rd item with marker *, and the color is compatible with the colors array(1st item will be 0 color, 2nd item will be 1 color)...
Like the result image, only color of the last of plt.scatter will be true.
I dont understand where I am wrong.
Please give me some solutions.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the same color normalization for all scatter plots. This normalization would need to span over the complete range of possible color values. Otherwise the first scatter doesn't know about the second scatter's range etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
colors = [0,1,1,0,1,4,1,3,2,4]
sizes = [500,500,300,300,300,500,500,300,300,300]
map1 = plt.cm.get_cmap("jet", 5)
norm = plt.Normalize(min(colors),max(colors))
kw = dict(cmap=map1, norm=norm)
plt.scatter(x[0:3], y[0:3], c=colors[0:3] ,s=sizes[0:3],marker="*",**kw)
plt.scatter(x[3:6], y[3:6], c=colors[3:6] ,s=sizes[3:6],marker="<",**kw)
plt.scatter(x[6:10], y[6:10], c=colors[6:10], s=sizes[6:10],marker="D",**kw)
plt.colorbar(ticks=range(5))
plt.clim(-0.5, 4.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is exactly what i need. Thank you very much.